# Sending local notifications from Xamarin.Forms with distinct topics

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, uilocalnotification

I have been implementing local notifications sent from a Xamarin.Forms app based on the sample
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications
Each local notification sent will get collapsed, which for a single topic is OK for me.

If however I wanted to send local notifications on more than one topic and each topic displayed a separate notification, how can that be achieved (interested in iOS and Android).

Remote notifications from a server in say FCM control this by allowing a Tag in the notification body but cannot see the way to achieve this with local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS varying the identifier in this call, allows control over distinct topics and will post local notifications separately...

```
public class UNNotificationRequest
:
public static UNNotificationRequest FromIdentifier(string identifier, UNNotificationContent content, UNNotificationTrigger? trigger);
```

For Android varying the id in this call allows the same...

```
class Android.App.NotificationManager
:
        public virtual void Notify(int id, Notification? notification);
```